# proxy configuration for angular app on production server

Tags: angular, proxy

is there any way to configure proxy configuration for production...

currently i am developing an angular app where i have used proxy.config.json on the development server...and it runs on the development serve
command:

`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json`

```
{
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "-my_api_link_",
      "secure": false,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
      },
      "changeOrigin":true
    }
  }
```

But for production it is not working ...is there any solution for this

Comment: Production does not need proxy configuration ....All apis call will be served from dedicated server and server will have some DNS mapping which will give base URL

Answer (score 0):

I guess you configure the proxyConfig in angular.json

```
  "options": {
        "browserTarget": "testProject:build",
        "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
      },
```